# How can I use checkboxes to filter events in FullCalendar?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, fullcalendar

I have a series of checkboxes to the left of my calendar that are, by default, checked. I want the corresponding events to be hidden when the user unchecks the checkbox to filter out what events they see.

```
<head>
<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
  var cal = $('#calendar')
    cal.fullCalendar({
    eventSources:
    {
            url: "...",
            id: "rto",
        }

    (function( $ ){
       $.fn.removeEvents = function() {
            cal.fullCalendar( 'removeEvents' );
       };
    })( jQuery );
});
</script>
</head>

<body>
  <form>
    <input type="checkbox" value="rto" checked>
  </form>

<script>
  if ($('#events').is(':unchecked')) {
            .removeEvents("rto");
            }
</script>

<div id="calendar" style="float:left; margin-top: 10px"></div>
</body>
```

This does not work at all. I replaced `cal.fullCalendar( 'removeEvents' );` with `alert("test");` and it still didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like there's is lot missing in your code;
1. all the scripts should gon in the script tag,
2. the plugin that needs to be included
3. Have you included Jquery as atleast?
4. exteneded function removeEvents needs to be called as below:

```
$("#elementId").removeEvents(parametersIfAny)
```

I think these could be the issues that you need to solve first

I dont think we have **:unchecked** in jquery. I think you need to do this

```
if (!$('#events').is(':checked')) { // Note "!" sign here (this indicates that the condition is inverted)
         $(element).removeEvents("rto")          
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I was only including the parts of my code that was specific to the question and I forgot to include script tags and jQuery. Also, I tried added the id and it's still not functioning, thanks anyways.